# Undefined reference error in C using CodeBlocks IDE

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am just playing around with code blocks and writing a very simple program, but I  get the undefined reference error... I copied the exact same code to somewhere else and compiled it in the terminal and works fine, but just doesn't work in code blocks.

my main.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "subfunc.h"

int main()
{
    printhello();
    return 0;
}
```

and then my subfunc.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "subfunc.h"

void printhello(void)
{
    printf("hello world in function\n");
}
```

and then my subfunc.h is:

```
void printhello(void);
```

Thanks

### UPDATE

Actually.. I figured it out. I right clicked the files subfunc.c and subfunc.h and select properties and went to build tab, I find the option for compile file and link file are not ticked. Thanks

Comment: The code seems good. the problem is probably in the link stage where the main.obj (the main.c compiled) and the subfunc.obj need to be linkage to one executable file.

Comment: Undefined reference to *what* ?  Always include the exact error message if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state exactly what the undefined error was but I'm betting it has something to do with either your `main()` or `printhello()` function.

Make sure you're linking *both* object files main.obj and subfunc.obj in your project after compiling your main.c and subfunc.c. This should automatically happen in codeblocks assuming you included both main.c and subfunc.c for the current project you're building.

Comment: Actually.. I think I really know why now haha. I right clicked the files subfunc.c and subfunc.h and select properties and went to build tab, I find the option for compile file and link file are not ticked

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 2):

[image]
See the above picture and compare with your project. Compare with only the Red colored circle. Ignore the remaining (Remaining are w.r.t my project/assignment)
In my_subfunction.h
write

```
    #ifndef __MY_SUBFUNC_H__
    #define __MY_SUBFUNC_H__


    #include<stdio.h>
    void printhello(void);
    #endif
```

In main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_subfunc.h"

int main()
{
    printhello();
    return 0;
}
```

and my_subfun.c:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_subfunc.h"

void printhello(void)
{
    printf("hello world in function\n");
}
```

I hope this helps..
Because this did work for me.

Comment: Because your header file name is my_subfunction.h. I think u might have forgotten to add "my_"

Comment: usually `<>` are used for "system wide" include file, while `""` are used for "local" include file; in this case `""` are more correct; the OP issue is about linking, as a comment explain. Moreover, your guard is wrong, the `#endif` *must* be at the end of the file.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Thanks for the correction. By mistake I put the #endif in the middle. Thanks A Lot

Comment: Actually.. I think I really know why now haha. I right clicked the files subfunc.c and subfunc.h and select properties and went to build tab, I find the option for compile file and link file are not ticked

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort